# Independent variables in the conditional variance GARCH(1,1)

Tags: regression, data-transformation, garch, conditional-variance

I am using a GARCH(1,1) model, and I would like to add some variables to my conditional variance.

I have the data for these variables, but I was wondering if I have to change these variables to variance-data themselves.

Let's say my data is 1, 4, 6, 8, 2. Before adding it as a variable to the conditional variance, do I have to transform it to (1-mean)/mean before I can add it? So my data would then be (1-4.2)/4.2, (4-4.2)/4.2, etc.

Comment: 1) It all depends on the software you use and the input it `requires`. 2) Conceptually, please include why you think you need that transformation.

Comment: @Jim, it's more so a conceptual question. I use stata, so the input would be something in the line of: -- arch log_return, het(L.var) arch(1) garch(1) -- The reason for me was that when transforming this data, it would explain more about the variance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible perspectives on the question. For example, you can have an idea of what the data generating process (DGP) could be, dictated by the knowledge about the physical/economic/... processes at hand or some theory about them. If you think it is a GARCH(1,1) with additional regressors, i.e. something like 
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
\mu_t &= \dots, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \gamma_1 x_1 + \dots + \gamma_k x_k, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d.(0,1),
\end{aligned}
then it is natural to include the additional regressors $x_1$ to $x_k$ as they are in the conditional variance equation instead of changing them from $x_i$ to $z_i:=\frac{x_i-\bar{x}_i}{\bar{x}_i}$ for $=1,\dots,k$.

If you have no idea about the transformation of the $x$s in the DGP, you may try different alternatives and see which one leads to best model fit, adjusted for the fact that more complex models tend to fit better even if the true model is not complex (e.g. by careful use of AIC or BIC or cross validation / out-of-sample evaluation).

If you want to prevent the possibility of getting a negative fitted value of the conditional variance, you might either (1) transform the $x$s to make them nonnegative and restrict the $\gamma$s to be nonnegative or (2) use, say, a log-GARCH model where $\log(\sigma_t^2)$ replaces $\sigma_t^2$ in the conditional variance equation. (Log-GARCH is an alternative to EGARCH and has certain advantages over the latter; see e.g. the [recent works](http://www.sucarrat.net/#Research) of Genaro Sucarrat and [his R packages](http://www.sucarrat.net/R/index.html) `lgarch` and `gets`). (2) might be a computationally simpler alternative than (1), but bare in mind that the interpretation of the two models is not identical.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My x's are in total 1, so for example x1 = 0.2, x2 = 0.5 and x3 = 0.3, so that's why i tried this transformation (and i would make a separate regression for each x).

Comment: That's called compositional data and there are some special methods for dealing with it. I am no expert, but including all of these in one equation would lead to perfect multicollinearity (I guess you know that already), so you may instead include all but one. A transformation making them linearly independent is probably not a good idea as the three variables together still can be summarized without loss of information as two variables...

Comment: Thanks again. Let's say I have 20 variables summing to 1, but with further inspection I'm only using 16. Would there in that case be any problem?

Comment: From the perspective of collinearity, there would not be a problem as long as at least one variable is left out.